# Why is my WCF server returning empty responses using protobuf-net?

Tags: .net, wcf, protobuf-net

I've updated an existing WCF application to add protobuf-net support.
Basically, I've :

- added protobuf-net.dll (.net 3.0) as a reference in the assembly containing all my data objects. This assembly is referenced by both my server and my client
- replaced [DataMember] by [DataMember(Order = x)] (using increasing ints as x)
- Updated all my OperationContracts with the ProtoBehavior attribute
- Updated my service reference

From the client, I call this method on the server :

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false), ProtoBehavior]
ConnectionData Join(string userId, string Password);
```

with ConnectionData being defined like this :

```
[DataContract]
public class ConnectionData
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public ConnectionStatusEnum ConnectionStatus; // this is a normal enum with five elements

    // .....

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public bool MustChangePassword;
}
```

Now, here's what's going on :

- If I debug the server, I see that a ConnectionData object is correctly initialized and returned in the Join method
- If I debug the client, I see a null object being returned from my Join call
- I've enabled WCF tracing to the maximum verbosity, nothing caught my eye in the Server's log, but in the Client log file I've seen this warning message :

> System.Runtime.Serialization.ElementIgnored
>   An unrecognized element was
>   encountered in the XML during
>   deserialization which was ignored.
>   Element   http://tempuri.org/:proto

I've sniffed my network trafic, and I don't blame protobuf-net for not being able to deserialize this :

```
<s:Body><JoinResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><proto/></JoinResponse></s:Body>
```

How can I further troubleshoot the problem and get protobuf-net to serialize my messages correctly?

---

I'm using protobuf-net r275

Comment: The config-based support is now there (as per your request): http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay - working hours, etc. Do both ends know about this change? Unfortunately, the WCF integration doesn't play very nicely with "mex"-generated proxies at the client, but works OK with assembly sharing.

Alternatively, there is some work in progress to use an endpoint behaviour that can be specified in the config; this isn't 100%, but should be very soon - and allows WCF to use protobuf-net transparently, with no midifications to the service contract (although the members still need to know about it, either through `[ProtoMember(n)]` etc, or `[DataMember(Order=n)]`.

Comment: Hi Marc; thanks for your quick answer. The shared assembly (which was the only one modified so far), the client and the server are in a single .sln and both reference the shared assembly project. Does that answer your question?

Comment: re app.config support, if I understand correctly, that would definitely be a very nice addition as it would allow for providing client with a Soap AND a protobuf enabled service, with a single service definition.

Comment: It does... I'll try to put the above into something to try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some more work in this area, and I **suspect** the problem is that you have a service reference (either via the IDE or via svcutil), which *even though* it re-uses the shared data-contracts, causes the contract interface to get duplicated (and loses the behavior attribute, making it broken).

Options:

- don't use a service-reference (use the channel directly, or subclass `ClientBase<T>`)
- use the new [endpoint configuration options](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html)
- hack the generated interface to include the behavior (creates maintenance problems)

If you aren't familiar with them, I plan on writing a blog entry for the first option in the next couple of days.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for your support and time. I'll try the .config thing and hopefully confirm you it solved the problem :)